# How to ignore NSTimer TimeInterval in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have the following scenario when using an NSTimer which fires every 1 second. In the code below, when I click restart, I want to go to first condition immediately, but this doesn't happen until after the 1 second event. Any ideas how I can do this without the one second delay?

```
int condition =0; //can only be 0, 1, or 2

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(timerEvent:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[timer fire];

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    seconds++;

    if(condition ==0)
       [self drawFoo];
    if(condition ==1)
       [self drawBoo];
    if(condition == 2)
       [self drawYoo];

  if(seconds >= duration){
    condition++;
    seconds =0;
   }

}

- (IBAction)reStart:(id)sender {
    condition = 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start your timer immediately and then re-trigger it:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(timerEvent:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[timer fire];

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeinterval target:self selector:@selector(timerEvent:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [timer fire];
    seconds++;

/...
```

Comment: Can't I just make the interval as a variable and set it to zero when I push reset? then set it back to one?

Comment: @user1529412 Calling `fire` is the proper solution. You get the event "now" plus at each interval.

Comment: Your snippet isn't exactly correct relative to my code, but I understood what you meant. Basically, when I need to return immediately, just fire the timer once with timeInterval = 0. Thank you sir.

Comment: Thinking of it once more it should probably also have worked if you had inserted `[timerFired timer:timer]` right after your `[timer fire]`. That would create a fake call which in your case should also work since you don't do anything with your `timer` object. Alas, the suggested approach is what I did on the past. Both ways should work :-)

Comment: I see. The idea of passing a timer and not doing anything felt little strange to me. Either way both answers helped me find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, there seem to be two obvious ways around your issue. The first is to immediately trigger the branch of the `if (condition == 0)` statement directly by calling the same code in the branch i.e.

```
- (IBAction)reStart:(id)sender {
     condition = 0;
     [self drawFoo];
  }
```

Alternatively you can format the code slightly different and have a separate method that is triggered in the `timerFired` method, and call this method in the `reStart:` method. This is, in effect, the same option as the first, however it is cleaner and more reusable.

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    seconds++;
    [self someCommonMethod:timer];
    condition++;
}

- (void)someCommonMethod:(id)param {
    if (condition == 0)
       [self drawFoo];
    if (condition == 1)
       [self drawBoo];
    if (condition == 2)
       [self drawYoo];
}

- (IBAction)reStart:(id)sender {
    condition = 0;
    [self someCommonMethod:someParamForConditions];
}
```

Comment: max_, obviously I know about solution1 but didn't want to do it that way. Could you explain your solution2 a bit more because I couldn't follow why do I need to pass the timer to the common method?

Comment: It's more reusable in the sense that you don't have to have the same code in different locations. Furthermore should the function that you'd like to be performed when `condition == 0` changes, you won't need to update the code in one area, but two. You don't, it's just future proofing the code, should you need to invalidate the timer upon a certain condition in the future.

Comment: I am not sure if this is quite correct, because even when I update the condition and seconds to zero when I hit restart, the fact that the counter still waits for 1 second to hit the event, means the seconds count will start one second later that I wanted it to. In other words, when I hit restart, I want to update immediately and start counting seconds immediately too.

Comment: Then @Thomas Killian's answer is correct. Your question wasn't clear that you wanted to restart the timer as well, from what you said, it sounded as if you just wanted to reset the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call it in your viewDidLoad instead as it will do the action you want when the view loads :)

Comment: Call what in ViewDidLoad? The condition is dependent on the seconds count.